# Tooth and Claw Ranking System

Tags: dragons, tooth-and-claw

I just finished [*Tooth and Claw*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooth_and_Claw_(novel)) by Jo Walton, and got a bit confused by the aristocratic ranking system. There's Eminents vs Eminence, Exalt vs Exalted, etc, and those are stacked on top of each other as well. As I understand it, these relate to medieval status ranks, but I'm not sure how because I can hardly get my head around how they're ordered.

**What are the order of gentle born rankings, and how do they relate to medieval rankings?**

Comment: Are those really the words used?  Because having two different strata, paronymic but with different temporal tenses or syntactic conjugation, is either quite illogical or quite innovative.

Comment: From the bits I read online, I could see two titles being used:  **Exalted** and **Blessed**.  Therefore, I venture that the four you mentioned are probably a mix of two forms of an honorific, a title, and an infinitive that you confused into the lot.  The book looks interesting, and I'll give it a go, but that will be much later.

Comment: @can-ned_food Yes, those are the ones used and no, it's not a mix.